# multiple ajax calls to async Action breaks code

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm writing a web application in .Net Core Framework and certain elements of the front end use Ajax calls to API that returns certain data.

If I'm on a page that requires 1 API call, it works fine, however as soon as I get on a page that makes more than 1 calls, debugging (well, going line by line in the code) becomes hell with the debugger jumping up and down the code) and in the end the results all end up as errors.

Rarely will I get the results if a website makes more calls, sometimes it happens but odds of that are.. 1 / 50 and this is unacceptable.

Weirdly enough, after I visit such page and then go back to a page that makes 1 call, even that 1 call ends with an error.

I'm not really sure what I need to include here as a code so I'll add both jquery and the action.

**Before I put any code here, I'd like to explain my question..**
I'd like to know what exactly is causing this, and why are the ajax calls causing parallel executions of the Action and how could I force that ajax calls are ran one by one or do anything else to fix this issue. I believe at most 30,40 calls should be made by some Views and if even 2 cause such issues, there's obviously a problem here, but unfortunately I'm not skilled enough yet to see and fix it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

jquery (I've removed pieces of code simply because they aren't relevant. it's just some class changes):

```
$(window).ready(function () {

$('.price').each(function (i, e) {
    var id = $(e).data('skinid');
    var exterior = $(e).data('exterior');
    var type = $(e).data('type');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Skin/GetPrice",
        data: { Id: id, Exterior : exterior, Type : type },
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",

    }).complete(function (data) {
        var price = data.responseJSON.price;
        if (data.responseJSON.querySuccessful)
        {
            if (data.responseJSON.listingExists)
            {
                //do stuff here
            }
            else
            {
                //other stuff here
            }
        }
        else
        {
                //print error..
        }
    });
});

});
```

Action is quite long so I'll short it up as well:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetPrice(int Id = 0, string Exterior = null, string Type = null)
{
    PriceViewModel model = null;
    if (_context.Skins.Any(x => x.Id == Id))
    {
        if (Type == "Skin")
        {
            Skin Query = _context.Skins.Where(x => x.Id == Id).Include(x => x.Weapon).Include(x => x.Quality).Select(x => x).Single();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    string uri = "/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=" + Query.Weapon.Name.Replace(" ", "%20") + "%20|%20" + Query.Name.Replace(" ", "%20") + "%20(" + Exterior.Replace(" ", "%20") + ")";

                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://steamcommunity.com");
                    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw in not success

                    var stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JObject data = JObject.Parse(stringResponse);

                    if (data["success"].Value<bool>())
                    {
                        if (data["lowest_price"] != null)
                        {
                            // return good model
                        }
                        //return no result model
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    // return error
                }
            }
        }

        if (Type == "Skin-List")
        {
            Skin Query = _context.Skins.Where(x => x.Id == Id).Include(x => x.Weapon).Include(x => x.Quality).Select(x => x).Single();

            Dictionary<Exterior, PriceViewModel> PossibleExteriors = new Dictionary<Exterior, PriceViewModel>();

            bool possible = false;
            foreach (Exterior e in _context.Exteriors)
            {
                if (e.Name == Query.BestExterior)
                    possible = true;

                if (possible)
                    PossibleExteriors.Add(e, null);

                if (e.Name == Query.WorstExterior)
                    possible = false;
            }
            List<Exterior> exteriors = PossibleExteriors.Keys.ToList();
            foreach (Exterior e in exteriors)
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://steamcommunity.com");
                        string uri = "/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=" + Query.Weapon.Name.Replace(" ", "%20") + "%20|%20" + Query.Name.Replace(" ", "%20") + "%20(" + e.Name.Replace(" ", "%20") + ")";
                        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw in not success

                        var stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        JObject data = JObject.Parse(stringResponse);

                        if (data["success"].Value<bool>())
                        {
                            if (data["lowest_price"] != null)
                            {
                                model = new PriceViewModel
                                {
                                    QuerySuccessful = true,
                                    ListingExists = true,
                                    ListingUrl = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/" + Query.Weapon.Name + " | " + Query.Name + " (" + e.Name.Replace(" ", "%20") + ")",
                                    Price = data["lowest_price"].ToString()
                                };
                                PossibleExteriors[e] = model;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                model = new PriceViewModel
                                {
                                    QuerySuccessful = true,
                                    ListingExists = false,
                                    ListingUrl = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/" + Query.Weapon.Name + " | " + Query.Name + " (" + e.Name.Replace(" ", "%20") + ")",
                                    Price = ""
                                };
                                PossibleExteriors[e] = model;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        model = new PriceViewModel
                        {
                            QuerySuccessful = false,
                            ListingExists = false,
                            Price = ""
                        };
                        PossibleExteriors[e] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (PossibleExteriors.Values.Any(x => x != null))
            {
                //return good model
            }
            else
            {
                //return empty
            }
        }
    }
    //return error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know what exactly is causing this, and why are the ajax calls causing parallel executions of the Action and how could I force that ajax calls are ran one by one or do anything else to fix this issue.

You've got a fundamental misunderstanding about asynchronous calls. This JavaScript will fire off a request, then continue into the next iteration of the loop *before getting a response*. The `complete` function will be called whenever an asynchronous call is completed, whenever that happens and in whatever order it happens in. This means that new calls are arriving faster than the application can return results, so it's working on more than one request at a time. Perfectly normal!

If these calls need to be made in a specific order, why not lump them all into one request? Pass a list of items into the `data` property and do a loop in C#.

If this has to be a loop in JavaScript, you'll need to wait for a response from the asynchronous call (basically make it synchronous) If you want to do this calls synchronously, as in call `GetPrice`, get a response, do something with the response, then go to the next iteration and repeat, you'll need to change the approach.

```
var $prices = $('.prices').map(function() {
    return new { Id: id, Exterior : exterior, Type : type }
});

getPrice($prices, 0);

function getPrice(prices, index) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Skin/GetPrice",
        data: prices[index] // if this were the whole prices list, you could do the loop in C# instead
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
    }).complete(function (data) {

       // do all that processing stuff

       index++;
       // if there are more prices to compute, call the function again
       if (prices.length - 1 >= index) {
           getPrice(prices, index);
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: I understand how async works, and I'm fine with the methodology behind it and I'd really like to utilize this completely, but obviously something in the code doesn't work properly and I'm curious why this is exactly happening. I am not sure your answer will work because you've mapped the prices into an array of objects, however when the complete function is done I have to edit the element itself. with my method I could just use `$(e).addClass()` etc. but I don't suppose this will work here. but I can add the element itself as a property of the object, right?

Comment: @DethoRhyne Yup, you could add the element as a property. From the OP: "and in the end the results all end up as errors." - what errors are you getting? Could you share those details?

Comment: After a long long debug session I realized that ajax, and the code in general is indeed working properly.
The problem was the API call itself. 
Inside the API call I refer to steamcommunity API which has a fixed limit of calls that can be made in certain time, so those http clients came back with 429 error (exceeded maximum call limit) what ended up hitting a typo in the catch block making the method crash and return 500 error.